# Run Python ZMQ Workers simultaneously

Tags: python, zeromq, distributed-computing, pyzmq

I am pretty new in the Python and at distributed systems.
I am using the ZeroMQ Venitlator-Worker-Sink configuration:
[Ventilator - Worker - Sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clcln.png)

Everything is working fine at the moment, my problem is, that I need a lot of workers. Every worker is doing the same work. 
At the moment every worker is working in his own Python file and has his own Output-Console.
If I have programm changes, I have to change (or copy) the code in every file.
Next problem is that I have to start/run every file, so it quiet annoying to start 12 files.
What are here the best solutions? Threads, processes?
I have to say that the goal is to run every worker on a diffrent raspberry pi.

Comment: Can the workers be a single class?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be more of a dev/ops problem.  You have your worker code, which is presumably a single codebase, on multiple distributed machines or instances.  You make a change to that codebase and you need the resulting code to be distributed to each instance, and then the process restarted.

To start, you should at minimum be using a source control system, like Git.  With such a system you could at least go to each instance and pull the most recent commit and restart. Beyond that, you could set up a system like Ansible to go out and run those actions on each instance initiated from a single command.

There's a whole host of other tools, strategies and services that will help you do those things in a myriad of different ways. Using Docker to create a single worker container and then distribute and run that container on your various instances is probably one of the more popular ways to do what you're after, but it'll require a more fundamental change to your infrastructure.

Hope this helps.